# How to fix incorrect delete?

Tags: java, conditional-statements

So here is a code that clean up text from symbols that not a alphabetic char. Then it split text for words. And then delte words that not starting from vowels and words that have not second char. 
But, when you enter big text String this function not working correct

```
input = new StringBuffer("some text will be here");
System.out.println("Начальная строка - " + input.toString());
input = new StringBuffer(input.toString().replaceAll("[^a-z A-Z А-Я а-я]", ""));
out = new StringTokenizer(input.toString());
System.out.println("Форматированная строка - " + input.toString());
n = (out.countTokens());
for (i = 0; i <= n - 1; i++) {
 tokenStr = new StringBuffer(out.nextToken());
 aChar = (tokenStr.charAt(0));
   if (tokenStr.length() > 1) {
     if (Here is check for vowels) {
       input.delete(input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString()),input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString())+ tokenStr.length() + 1);
     }
   } else {
     input.delete(input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString()),input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString())+ tokenStr.length() + 1);
   }

}
```

Comment: What's the difference between the code under  `if` and `else`?

Comment: else is for delete single char

Comment: So what the code under `if` does?

Comment: It delete words that not starts from vowels

Comment: The code is exactly the same for both branches so you might want to double check that.

Comment: Even if I use `input.deleteCharAt(input.indexOf(tokenStr.toString()));` I will get the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest to use guava library Strings utilities http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/StringsExplained

Comment: There are also methods like removeFrom, strip, and so on

Comment: I see, but i have to use only StringBuffer and StringTokenizer